# What's the equivalent of "HttpUtility.UrlEncode" in javascript (nodejs)?

Tags: c#, node.js, urlencode

I'm trying to **URLEncode** 40 bytes in C# and Node.

Let's take this as an example of my 40 bytes:

```
86,63,228,90,223,138,78,142,224,198,114,68,205,42,206,252,233,190,184,160,199,64,124,176,104,189,106,187,103,105,141,45,16,210,219,189,63,56,150,150
```

And let's say I'm using C#'s **HttpUtility.UrlEncode(bytes)**

While in C# I get something that looks like this:

```
V%3f%e4Z%df%8aN%8e%e0%c6rD%cd*%ce%fc%e9%be%b8%a0%c7%40%7c%b0h%bdj%bbgi%8d-%10%d2%db%bd%3f8%96%96
```

**In nodejs using encodeURI() I get this:**

```
encodeURI(new Buffer([86,63,228,90,223,138,78,142,224,198,114,68,205,42,206,252,233,190,184,160,199,64,124,176,104,189,106,187,103,105,141,45,16,210,219,189,63,56,150,150]))

   => 'V?%EF%BF%BDZ%DF%8AN%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BDrD%EF%BF%BD*%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%E9%BE%B8%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD@%7C%EF%BF%BDh%EF%BF%BDj%EF%BF%BDgi%EF%BF%BD-%60%EF%BF%BD%60Ua%00%EF%BF%BD%17'
```

**And encodeURIComponent returns**

```
    encodeURIComponent(new Buffer([86,63,228,90,223,138,78,142,224,198,114,68,205,42,206,252,233,190,184,160,199,64,124,176,104,189,106,187,103,105,141,45,16,210,219,189,63,56,150,150]))
=> 'V%3F%EF%BF%BDZ%DF%8AN%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BDrD%EF%BF%BD*%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%E9%BE%B8%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%40%7C%EF%BF%BDh%EF%BF%BDj%EF%BF%BDgi%EF%BF%BD-%10%EF%BF%BD%DB%BD%3F8%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD'
```

Am I missing something? Is there a URLEncode that is able to produce de same C# encode output?

Comment: Does your byte array represent string in certain encooding or it's some random byte array?

Comment: That's a random byte array

Comment: Then why url encode it? Convert it to hex or base64 instead - url encoding is for strings. On certain byte arrays (that do not represent valid unicode string) what you are trying to do will fail.

Comment: URL-encoding is for *strings* to make them safe to be used within an URL. You are trying to serialize bytes. Something like base64 will be more suitable there.

Comment: I know guys, the thing is I don't control the C# side. So I need to respect the existing implementation and be able to produce the same output than C#. Those random bytes are actually the output an encryption.

Comment: Hopefully you can at least tell authors of C# side that what they are doing makes no sense.

Comment: That's an option but I would like to know exactly how UrlEncode works in C#. As far as I can see, all characters that have a ASCII representation are translated to it's value while all other non ASCII  characters are converted to their hex value prefixed with %. But there are exception for example, decimal 63 is converted to %3f while it's ASCII code is "?".

Comment: Does the encodeUriComponent output not work? Have you tried it? I appreciate that there are small differences (e.g. case of the percent-encoding), but If it works, job done.

Comment: Yes I tried it. That's the last example in my post. But the output is still different from C# output. I think C# does some sort of escaping before encoding but that's not documented

Comment: *“but I would like to know exactly how UrlEncode works in C#.”* – https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/httpserverutility.cs,1357

Comment: URL encoding specification allows several variations. e.g. %2A and %2a are equivalent, %3f and ? are equivalent. usually this is fine because you just pass the output to URLDecode to get back what you started with. Why do **you** need the output to be the same? Doesn't it work?